# redirect a page via ajax call in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I want to redirect a another page using ajax call. I used below code but it doesn't redirect

```
def show_item_details
   @itm_id=params[:Id]
   redirect_to  prd_item_path(@itm_id)
end
```

ajax code

```
   $.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      url: url,
      dataType:"json",
      data: {PrdId: parseInt(prdId)},
      success:function(result){
          setItemDetails(result)
      }
  });
```

Comment: ajax requests don't follow redirect headers by default. After all, the whole point of ajax is avoid to postbacks, redirects, page refreshes etc. If you want to do a redirect like this, you need to use a regular postback. There's actually no reason to use ajax for this, because by redirecting you lose the benefits of ajax.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways.

One option would be to pass the new location from the controller to the frontend and redirect with javascript.

```
success:function(result){
    window.location.href = result;
}
```

Other option would be to avoid redirecting but rendering the new page and showing the html.

```
success:function(result){
    $('body').html(result);
}
```

This is easy on javascript but all the work has to be done in the controller.

Hope this helps!